# cross join in SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE RESTful Web Service app., using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file. I am using an inMemoryDatabase : **H2 Database Engine**

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I have these objects:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_menu_alert_notification")
public class MenuAlertNotification implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;    



    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "menu_alert_id")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="name")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    protected MenuAlert menuAlert;
...
}



@Entity
@Table(name="t_menu_alert")
public class MenuAlert implements Serializable {


    public MenuAlert() {
    }



    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="name")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    Menu menu;

..

}





@Entity
@Table(name = "t_menu")
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "name", "address", "description" })
public class Menu implements Serializable {





    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;



    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

..

}
```

I have this method in the repository class that extends from a CrudRepository

```
@Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("update MenuAlertNotification n set n.read = :status where n.id in :notificationIdList and n.menuAlert.menu.user.id = :userId")
    void changeMenuNotificationListReadStatus(  @Param("notificationIdList") List<Long> notificationIdList, 
                                                    @Param("userId") long userId, 
                                                    @Param("status") boolean status);
}
```

But when I run this method I have this error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [update t_menu_alert_notification cross join  set is_read=? where (id in (?)) and user_id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:279)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)

    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "UPDATE T_MENU_ALERT_NOTIFICATION CROSS[*] JOIN  SET IS_READ=? WHERE (ID IN (?)) AND USER_ID=? "; expected "., AS, SET"; SQL statement:
update t_menu_alert_notification cross join  set is_read=? where (id in (?)) and user_id=? [42001-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:217)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:555)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.read(Parser.java:3518)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseUpdateSetClause(Parser.java:785)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseUpdate(Parser.java:780)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:485)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:335)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:311)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:278)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:611)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:549)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1247)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:304)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:311)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    ... 73 more
```

Comment: are you using h2(hickari) database?

Comment: Implicit `JOIN`s (`n.menuAlert.menu.user`) are not allowed in JPQL `UPDATE` statements. You need to `SELECT` and then `UPDATE`

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct):

> No joins, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL
>   query.

So you need to find `n.menuAlert` first, then pass as parameter to update query or using native query.